# Mongoose can't save document to the database for one particular collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a function

```
function generateInvoice(data) {
  const cdate = new moment.tz('GMT').toDate();
  let invoiceData = {
    date: cdate,
    paidStatus: true,
    amount: data.amount,
    userId: data.userId
  }

  if (data.planName && data.planTypeName) {
    invoiceData.item = `${data.planName} - ${data.planTypeName}`
    invoiceData.quantity = data.seats || data.slots;
  }
  if (data.credits) {
    invoiceData.item = 'Credits';
    invoiceData.quantity = data.credits;
  }

  return Invoice.create(invoiceData).then((data)=>{
    data.invoiceId = data._id.toString().slice(-5);
    return data.save().then((data)=>{console.log(data); return data.invoiceId}).catch((err)=>{
      throw new ErroWithStatusCode(500, 'Sorry, we seem to be facing some issue right now. Please, try again later.', err);
    })
  })
}
```

and this is how I am using this function

```
return generateInvoice(invoiceData).then((data)=>{
    newBooking.orderId = data;
    id = data;
    return newBooking.save().then((booking) => {
      return booking;
    }).catch((err) => {
      throw new ErroWithStatusCode(500, 'Sorry, we are facing some issue right now. Please try again later.')
    })
});
```

The issue is that I can't find `invoiceData` in my `invoices` collection. The `data` in the callback function of `then` block is the document, but I can't find the same document in the invoices collection.

All the promises are getting resolved. It is not falling in the catch block, I am receiving valid data from `Invoice.create(invoiceData)`.

Also, `newBooking.save()` function is working as expected. So, that's what is bothering me the most, as to why is it not working for one specific collection.

What could be the reason behind it?

**EDIT: This is the invoice schema**

```
const InvoiceSchema = new Schema({
  item: String,
  paidStatus: Boolean,
  quantity: String,
  amount: Number,
  invoiceId: String,
  userId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  date: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},
  __v: {type: Number, select: false}

}, {strict: true})

export default mongoose.model('Invoice', InvoiceSchema);
```

And I am not receiving any error, the booking is successful. I tried logging the data received in the then block, and it is a valid document, as I have already mentioned above.

**EDIT: The following is the complete code that invovlves the use of `generateInvoice` function:** [book.js](https://gist.github.com/relentless-coder/394f65156b07b196894d41fcbbf34fd0)

Comment: might be issue with modal. can you share your modal

Comment: There is no `.catch()` clause for your `Invoice.create` call – maybe try adding that and see if it reveals anything interesting.

Comment: @BipinChandraTripathi I have updated my question

Comment: @d0gb3r7 there is no error, this is just a part of the process, in a chain of promises, which succeeds.

Comment: Alright – I tried to run your code locally, and `generateInvoice` creates a DB entry as expected. The "how I am using this function" block, however, is not usable as-is (presumably `newBooking` and `id` are defined in an outer scope in your program).

Since this question is difficult to reproduce for other people, I would suggest trying to recreate the problem in a full, self-contained example (e.g. in a GitHub gist). You might even find the solution yourself along the way.

Comment: @d0gb3r7 hey, I have updated my question and added the gist.

Comment: @AyushBahuguna Thanks for the sample; however, the code in the gist is adding _more_ unrelated stuff, rather than narrowing down the issue. I was hoping for what StackOverflow calls a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example": https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Insted of

```
return Invoice.create(invoiceData).then((data)=>{...
```

Try

```
new Invoice(invoiceData).save((err,data)=>{
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    return data._id;
})
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer? How is one thing different from the other? Also, I have already tried that and didn't work. Is your solution working for you?

Comment: try logging err if still problem then make a small example for that and let us test then you can also try deleting the old file and create a new file and code in that